# Material 2 sidenav doesn't load css files

Tags: css, angular, material-design, angular-cli, angular-material2

I am working with angular cli and angular material 2. Buttons an toolbars get their right design an color, but when I want to implement a sidenav the button click will add a `.mdsidenav-opening`class, but there is no css rule.

```
<md-sidenav-layout fullscreen>
 <md-sidenav #sidenav>
    <md-nav-list *shellNoRender>
      <a md-list-item *ngFor="let view of views">
        <md-icon md-list-icon>{{view.icon}}</md-icon>
        <span md-line>{{view.name}}</span>
        <span md-line>{{view.description}}</span>
      </a>
    </md-nav-list>
  </md-sidenav>
  <md-toolbar color="primary">
    <button md-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
      <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
    </button>
    Puppy Love
  </md-toolbar>
  <router-outlet *shellNoRender></router-outlet>
</md-sidenav-layout>
```